# php destructor being called twice

Tags: php, destructor

can someone explain why the parent class destructor is being called twice? I was under the impression that a child class could only call a parent's destructor by using: parent::__destruct()

```
class test {

    public $test1 = "this is a test of a pulic property";
    private $test2 = "this is a test of a private property";
    protected $test3 = "this is a test of a protected property";
    const hello = 900000;

    function __construct($h){
        //echo 'this is the constructor test '.$h;
    }

    function x($x2){
        echo ' this is fn x'.$x2;
    }
    function y(){
        print "this is fn y";
    }

    function __destruct(){
        echo '<br>now calling the destructor<br>';
    }
}

class hey extends test {

    function hey(){
        $this->x('<br>from the host with the most');
        echo ' <br>from hey class'.$this->test3;
    }
}

$obj = new test("this is an \"arg\" sent to instance of test");
$obj2 = new hey();
echo $obj2::hello;
/*
 the result:
 this is fn x
 from the host with the most 
 from hey classthis is a test of a protected property900000
 now calling the destructor

 now calling the destructor
 */
```

Comment: It seems you are trying to access in hey a private variable from test class

Comment: $test3 is protected which means hey class inherited it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This only applies if the `__destruct` method is overridden in the child.  For example:

```
//parent
public function __destruct() {
   echo 'goodbye from parent';
}
//child
public function __destruct() {
   echo 'goodbye from child';
}
```

... will output:

```
goodbye from parentgoodbye from child
```

However, this:

```
//child
public function __destruct() {
   echo parent::__destruct() . "\n";
   echo 'goodbye from child';
}
```

Will output:

```
goodbye from parent
goodbye from child
```

If you do not override, it calls the parent destructor implicitly.

Comment: seems like a bug, because the php docs say that the destructor works just like the constructor in that they are not called by the child unless the child uses "parent::" http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php  and it's true the parent constructor is not called by the inheriting child in my example but the destructor seems to ignore what the docs say

Comment: @zero no, it only applies if the method is overridden.  The above applies to the `__construct`or as well: "Parent constructors are not called implicitly *if* the child class defines a constructor."

Comment: yeah you're right, seems strange though. is it like that in most other oop style languages or is that a php thing?

Comment: @zero I'm not sure -- Java has no destructors and its constructors *sort* of work the same way, but in Java you are required to call the equivalent of `parent::__construct`

Answer (score 4):

```
$obj = new test("this is an \"arg\" sent to instance of test");
$obj2 = new hey();
```

You have two objects being created here.  Both of which will destruct at the end of your script.

Since class `hey` doesn't define a destruct method it calls to the parent class for a destruct.  If you define a destruct in the child class and run your code you'll notice that it no longer hits the parent.

But you're still seeing the `test` destruct because you're creating an object of type `test` in the line `$obj = new test("this is an \"arg\" sent to instance of test");`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `hey` class inherits the `__destruct` method from its parent. So, when the `test` object is destroyed, it is called, and when the `hey` object is destroyed, it is called again.

Consider this change:

```
class hey extends test{
    function hey(){
        $this->x('<br>from the host with the most');
        echo ' <br>from hey class'.$this->test3;
    }

    function __destruct(){
    }
}
```

Then, your destruct message will only output once.

Sample (your code): http://codepad.org/3QnRCFsf

Sample (changed code): http://codepad.org/fj3M1IuO

Answer (score 1):

Its only an impression  ....

[The PHP DOC On Destructor](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

> Like constructors, parent destructors will not be **called implicitly by the engine**. In order to run a parent destructor, one would have to explicitly call parent::__destruct() in the destructor body.
>
> The destructor will be called even if script execution is stopped using exit(). Calling exit() in a destructor will prevent the remaining shutdown routines from executing.

if you don't what then you need to overwrite it

Example

```
class test {
    function __destruct() {
        var_dump(__CLASS__);
    }
}
class hey extends test {

    function __destruct() {   // <------ over write it 
    }
}
$obj = new test();
$obj2 = new hey();
```